# Unable to convert string date with GMT for Nsdate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone, nslocale

I have a string like a below example

```
2013-12-28T8:15:00+03:00
```

but i want to convert to NSDate with same format here is my code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterInBoundSegment = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatterInBoundSegment setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"];

[dateFormatterInBoundSegment setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

NSDate *dateInboundSegment = [dateFormatterInBoundSegment dateFromString:@"2013-12-28T8:15:00+03:00"];

NSLog(@"Formatted date %@",dateInboundSegment);
```

And result printed like this

```
Formatted date 2013-12-28 05:15:00 +0000
```

I want to convert to nsdate with GMT +3 like string ,result should be like this

```
2013-12-28T8:15:00+03:00
```

Comment: so why you are setting it to UTC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDate doesn't store the time zone, NSDate is just a number that represents a date. When you print it on the screen, it's just formatted like that, but your date and that one are the same.

This:

```
2013-12-28 05:15:00 +0000
```

and this:

```
2013-12-28T8:15:00+03:00
```

Represent the same date, just printed in a different way.

When you do this: `NSLog(@"Formatted date %@",dateInboundSegment);`  You are not specifying how the date has to be formatted to string, so it's using a default mode.

If you want to print the NSDate with the proper timezone, you need to create a string with a formatter and set the timezone.

Comment: What is the dateformtter should i use it for print the below date after adding 3 hours for GMT like string?

Comment: Just create a NSDateFormatter and set the timezone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772095/ios-nsdateformatter-timezone

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the `NSDate` value, not the formatted string. `NSDate` doesn't hold any format, and it's printed using the default format.

In order to print a string with your desired format, you must call:

`[dateFormatterInBoundSegment stringFromDate:myDate];`